# How to define dynamic drop-down menu (example).?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to re-create the view given in the [site](http://nvd.nist.gov/cvss.cfm?calculator&version=2) under the **Base Score Metrics**, when I click on it would expand and another click would collapse the details included in it.

I don't think this is native html functionality perhaps I have to use some third party plugin for it. Please tell me know how can I achieve the effect coded in the website given in the example.

**Collapsed view**
[image]

**Expanded view**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Look into JQuery's UI framework, specifically http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @ElliotM looks neat can i add like further elements radio button in it as well.

Comment: You can put anything inside them.

Comment: @ElliotM post this ans so i can acccept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's UI framework, specifically jqueryui.com/accordion, allows you to do just that.

You can put any elements inside those tabs, and it will work as if it were a static page.